# Python Mock UnitTest and Database

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I want to stub out a database call when I test a method I have in my code. All I want it to do is return me values but I cannot seem to get that far.

```py
def loadSummary(appModel):
    stmt = 'Select * from Table'
    for row in appModel.session.query(*t.columnNames()).from_statement(stmt).all():
        t.append(row)
    return t

def test_loadSummary(self):
    appModel = Mock()
    query = appModel.session.query.return_value
    query.from_statment.return_value = ['test1', 'test2']
    expected = loadSummary(appModel)
```

I get the following error

```py
for row in appModel.session.query(*t.columnNames()).from_statement(stmt).all():
TypeError: 'Mock' object is not iterable
```

So its like its not getting passed into the method at all even though it works in the shell no problem.

```py
>>> appModel.session.query('').from_statment('stmt')
['test1', 'test2']
```

I then tried using mock.patch.object

```py
class MockAppContoller(object):
    def from_from_statement(self, stmt):
        return ['test1', 'test2']

def test_loadSummary(self):
    with mock.patch.object(loadSummary, 'appModel') as mock_appModel:
        mock_appModel.return_value = MockAppContoller()
```

I get the following error

```
2014-04-09 13:20:53,276 root ERROR Code failed with error:
<function loadSummary at 0x0D814AF0> does not have the attribute 'appModel'
```

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: It is `sqlalchemy` you are using, right?

Comment: Yes. I am using SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error appears to be here:

```
 query.from_statment.return_value = ['test1', 'test2']
```

Should be:

```
 query.from_statement.return_value.all.return_value = ['test1', 'test2']
```

It works in the shell for you because you aren't using the same code

```
>>> appModel.session.query('').from_statement('stmt')
['test1', 'test2']
```

Would fail if you actually tried

```
>>> appModel.session.query('').from_statment('stmt').all()
['test1', 'test2']
```

Comment: <!-- language: lang-py -->

    >>> appModel.session.query('').from_statment('stmt').all()
    ['test1', 'test2']

    >>> for x in appModel.session.query().from_statement(stmt).all():
    ...     print x
    ...     
    2014-04-09 17:01:56,276 root ERROR Code failed with error:
    'Mock' object is not iterable
Still getting the same result besides that. Once I try and pass it to another object.

Comment: You also have a spelling mistake in `from_statment`. Which should be `from_statement` to match the code under test.

Comment: Whoops, amateur mistake. Thanks aychedee.

Comment: Don't worry! It gets harder to spot that stuff when mocking because the error messages are totally abstract and unrelated :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I came up with was this but its not as neat as using Mock

```py
class mockAppModel(object):
    def from_from_statement(self, stmt):       
        t = []
        t.appendRow('row1', 'row2')
        return t

class mockFromStmt(object): #This is the ONE parameter constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self._all = mockAppModel()

    def all(self):  #This is the needed all method
        return self._all.from_from_statement('')

class mockQuery(object): #This is the ONE parameter constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self._from_statement = mockFromStmt()

    def from_statement(self, placeHolder): #This is used to mimic the query.from_statement() call
        return self._from_statement 

class mockSession(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._query = mockQuery()

    def query(self, *args):  #This is used to mimic the session.query call
        return self._query

class mockAppModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = mockSession()
```